# Umbraco 7: Content from property not rendering after changing the property alias name

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, umbraco, umbraco7

I have a document type set up and I renamed the document type as well as the property name and alias, and now the content is not rendering anymore. This is how I get my content with the property in my View:

```
var items = Umbraco.Content(1123).newPropertyName;
```

and then I use foreach to get what I want. Here the integer parameter is the content type id, and newPropertyName is the property alias.
This worked fine before changing the name, any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My first suggestion would be to republish all of your content because the cache will likely contain versions with the old property alias.

http:///umbraco/dialogs/republish.aspx?xml=true

This will only republish pages that are already published, you don't need to worry about it publishing unpublished content.

See http://our.umbraco.org/wiki/reference/api-cheatsheet/publishing-and-republishing

Simon